# Create Local Database Cache - Use SQL Server change tracking is disabled

Tags: visual-studio-2010, microsoft-sync-framework, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to create a new "Local Database Cache" item in Visual Studio 2010 to sync against a local Sql Server Express 2008 R2 database.

When the wizard pops up though the "Use SQL Server change tracking" checkbox is disabled. Any ideas? I tried running

```
ALTER DATABASE MY_Database SET CHANGE_TRACKING = ON
```

but that had no effect.

Cheers,

Alex..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out..

The database was set to SQL Server 2000 compatibility, set it to SQL Server 2008 and all is good...